# what is the C++/CLI syntax to subscribe for events?

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

I'm updating some old Managed C++ code with lines like this:

```
instanceOfEventSource->add_OnMyEvent( 
    new EventSource::MyEventHandlerDelegate(this, MyEventHandlerMethod) );
```

where

- **EventSource** is the class that publishes events
- **instanceOfEventSource** is an instance of that class
- **EventSource::MyEventHandlerDelegate** is the delegate type for the event
- **MyEventHandlerMethod** is a (non-static) method within the current class (of which "this" is an instance) with the signature matching EventSource::MyEventHandlerDelegate

What is the right syntax for this in C++/CLI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax is similar to C#'s, in other words, `+=` is overloaded to make this possible:

```
instanceOfEventSource.MyEvent +=
    gcnew EventSource::MyEventHandlerDelegate(this, &MyClass::MyEventHandlerMethod);
```

Analogously for removal. Unlike C#, however, you may not omit the explicit instantiation of the event handler delegate so this produces quite long-winded code.

Comment: Should you not be using [gcnew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te3ecsc8(VS.80).aspx)?

Comment: I had to use gcnew, and I also found I had to write "@MyClass::MyEventHandlerMethod" instead of just "MyEventHandlerMethod".   But this took me where I needed to go -- thanks!!

Comment: Right about `gcnew`, I just didn't change this part of the code. And right about the method, as well. :-/

Answer (score 2):

I just spent half an hour trying to figure out how to register a static method as callback method for an event. While the OP did not specifically ask for registering static methods, this will be helpful to others facing the same problem. It's actually very simple, in that case the delegate constructor takes just one parameter for the static target method.

Example:

```
System::EventHandler^ h = gcnew System::EventHandler(&MyClass::MyStaticCallbackMethod);
```