# Register to C# event from C++/CLI

Tags: events, c++-cli, interop

I'm writing C++ code that calls C# code. The C# may need to invoke methods back in the C++ code. If both parts were C# I think I would use following mechanism. Please note I pass EventHandler from `ShouldBCpp` to `Csharp` instead of registering in `ShouldBCpp` since `ShouldBCpp` does not know what `csharp` points to (& can't change `CsharpBase`).

```
public abstract class CsharpBase
{
    public abstract void SomeMethodDoingActionInB();
}
public class Csharp : CsharpBase
{
    public Csharp(EventHandler f)
    {
        MySpecialHook += f;
    }
    public event EventHandler MySpecialHook;

    public override void SomeMethodDoingActionInB()
    {
        if (MySpecialHook != null)
            MySpecialHook(this, null);
    } 
}

public class ShouldBCpp
{
    public CsharpBase csharp;
    public ShouldBCpp()
    {
        csharp = new Csharp(NotificationFromClassB); // actually using Activator::CreateInstance
    }
    public void NotificationFromClassB(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    public void Go()
    {
       csharp.SomeMethodDoingActionInB();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ShouldBCpp shouldBCpp = new ShouldBCpp();
        shouldBCpp.Go();
    }
}
```

Question is how to write ShouldBCpp in C++/CLI. Bonus points for using `delegate` :)

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to help yourself?  Some of the popular decompilers can decompile MSIL to C++/CLI, even if the MSIL originally came from a different language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hooking a C# event from C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386508/hooking-a-c-sharp-event-from-c-cli)

Answer (score 2):

A simple translation to C++/CLI would look like this:

```
public ref class IsCppCLI
{
public:
    CsharpBase^ csharp;

    IsCppCLI()
    {
        csharp = gcnew Csharp(gcnew EventHandler(this, &IsCppCLI::NotificationFromClassB));

        // You didn't show your Activator code, 
        // but I believe it would translate to C++/CLI as this:
        csharp = dynamic_cast<CsharpBase^>(
            Activator::CreateInstance(
                Csharp::typeid, 
                gcnew array<Object^> {
                    gcnew EventHandler(this, &IsCppCLI::NotificationFromClassB)}));
    }

    void NotificationFromClassB(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
    {
    }

    void Go()
    {
       csharp->SomeMethodDoingActionInB();
    }
}
```