# please help me! detect event whenther phone device connected to computer via usb port + C#

Tags: c#, iphone, device

```
private const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
    private const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004;
    private const int DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME = 0x00000002;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        int devType;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
        {
            case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL: 
                devType = Marshal.ReadInt32(m.LParam, 4);
                if (devType == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("connect");
                }
                break;

            case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE: 
                devType = Marshal.ReadInt32(m.LParam, 4);
                if (devType == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
                    MessageBox.Show("not connect");
                break;
        }
    }
```

function detected the USB connect event. But when connecting the phone, it is not detected.
I want when connecting the phone device to also appear the same message as when connecting the usb. Please help.
Thank you very much

Comment: What `devType` you got when connecting a phone? Looks like the phone does not provide any logical disk volume when connecting and thus you only receive events with `devType` other then `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME`

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070890/register-to-c-sharp-event-from-c-cli

Comment: thank you. but I'm not good at c++. I don't understand about it.

Comment: devType = 2 when connecting usb. for unidentified phone devices. because the event is not caught