# Subscribing to C# EventHandler events from C++\CLI

Tags: c#, events, delegates, c++-cli

I have the following C# code, which uses the generic `EventHandler` delegate:

```
public class EventSource
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SomethingHappened;
}
```

I'm trying to subscribe to this event from a C++\CLI code:

```
public ref class EventSink
{
public:
    void Handler(Object^ sender, MyEventArgs^ args) 
    {
         DoSomthing(args);
    }
};

class Manager
{
private:
    gcroot<EventSource^> _eventSource;
    gcroot<EventSink^> _eventSink;

public:
    Manager()
    {
        _eventSource = gcnew EventSource();
        _eventSink = gcnew EventSink();

        _eventSource->SomethingHappened += // What do I put here?
    }
}
```

How do I instantiate a `EventHandler` delegate to pass to the `_eventSource->SomethingHappened.Add` property?

Comment: [Does this help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489626/what-is-the-c-cli-syntax-to-subscribe-for-events)

Comment: You'll make your life a wholeheckofalot easier when you subscribe the event in the constructor of the EventSink class.  There is no point at all in doing it in the Manager class from what you've posted.